# Does $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\omega\}$ satisfy true arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, ordinals, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Does $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\omega\}$ satisfy true arithmetic?(whereas $\omega$ is greater than any natural number) Even if not the standard model of natural number?
I believe it does, but I am not quite sure because it leads me to that the successor of omega is the same as omega.

Comment: What is “true arithmetic?”

Comment: This set doesn’t satisfy mathematical induction, which makes it difficult to use.

Comment: ω+1=ω, and ω+2=ω, ω+3=ω.. such a thing doesn't happen in N.

Comment: @imidak what axiom does it contradict?

Comment: For any n in N, there is unique k such that n+k=n. In fact such k is 0 for any n. But this becomes false if N is changed to N∪{ω}. For ω, there is k such that ω+k=ω, but such k is not unique.

Comment: In fact I have not heard the term true arithmetic but I found the term in wikipedia : 'true arithmetic is the set of all true first-order statements about the arithmetic of natural numbers'. Is it what you are meaning?

Comment: It doesn't even have arithmetic defined on all of it. What is $ω+ω$? $2ω$ is not in there.

Comment: @Conifold why can’t $\omega+\omega=\omega\cdot \omega=\omega?$ There are lots of reasons this isn’t a good model of arithmetic, but this is not it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because that isn't "true" arithmetic. The question is not about cooking up some random algebraic structure.

Comment: @Conifold I haven’t yet seen a definition of “true arithmetic.” The definition in comments above doesn’t seem to preclude these values.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am not sure what that is either. But $ω$ comes with algebraic properties and $ω+ω\neq ω$, so yours isn't.

Comment: You keep using vague statement. The only possible definition for $2+\omega$ and $2\cdot \omega$ and $\omega\cdot \omega$ in this set is $\omega.$ Certainly, this set has an algebra equal to the algebra of finite cardinals. If you don’t know what “true arithmetic” is, it is a bit bold to insist you know for sure what can been called algebraic and what can’t.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is not the only possible definition if you treat $ω$ as a mere symbol and introduce some arbitrary operations with it. Why not $ω+ω=1$? And if you assume that addition involving ω is the same as ordinal addition, like the answer below, then $ω+ω≠ω$. There is no need to know what precisely X is to say what it isn't.

Comment: @Conifold the OP is talking about a model. Models include the elements and no others. And $\omega+\omega=\omega$ if $\omega$ is any infinite cardinal. (It is not if $\omega$ is an ordinal, which is a usual meaning of $\omega.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So in your definition of "true arithmetic" ω is a cardinal? It is not like models do not have ordinals in them or one is "better" than the other. The real answer is that it doesn't work no matter how operations on ω are defined, your way or any other. But one still has to assume something about "true arithmetic" even for that.

Comment: @Conifold I don’t have a definition yet. You were the one who said I was wrong, sans definition. I am taking one example, the most likely one, to my mind, given the model set proposed, including “where $\omega$ is greater than any natural number.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There is one definition proposed in the answer. Both cardinal and ordinal versions fail it for various reasons, and idempotent addition is no better than undefined addition as a reason for that.

Comment: Setting $\omega + 1 = \omega$ you do indeed get a valid model, not for full Peano Arithmetic, but for the weaker (and quite important) sub-theory of [Robinson Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic#Metamathematics) $Q$. The only problematic axioms with regard to $\omega$ are the induction axioms, and they are missing in $Q$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that by true arithmetic, hence TA, you mean the set of sentences which are satisfied by the standard model $(\mathbb N,+,\cdot,<,0,1)$. That being said, your set is not even a model of PA:

Indeed, the sentence $\forall x (1+x\neq x)$ is provable in PA, and can't hold in your model, assuming addition involving $\omega$ is the same as ordinal addition.

Alternatively, if $M\models $PA extends $\mathbb N$ and $c\in M\setminus \mathbb N$, then $c+1\in M\setminus\mathbb N$. Then $\{c+n:n\in\mathbb N\}$is an infinite set contained in $M\setminus \mathbb N$, so there must always be infinitely many non-standard elements.

Comment: (+1) but: "assuming addition involving $\omega$ is the same as ordinal addition" -- it can't be, since then the result of $\omega+_M 1$ would be the ordinal usually written $\omega+1$, which is _not_ in the set.

Comment: A better argument could be: PA includes the axioms $x+1\ne 0$ and $x+1=y+1\implies x=y$, so if the successor function extends the usual successor function on $\mathbb N$, the only element that's available to be $\omega+1$ is $\omega$ itself. (Which is then in turn eliminated by the argument in this answer).